# AutoAdjusting Multi Line Placeholder Objective-C UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, placeholder

I am currenlty working on an ios project where I need to have a text field that can have the placeholder wrapped in it whenever needed

The placeholder is being taken as a user input so at times the text can be long and can extend to a couple of lines.

I tried this   `UITextView.placeholderLabel.numberOfLines = 0;` which doesnt seem to do the job.

Any good documentation would or references would be helpful too

Comment: Are you setting a fixed height for your text view? Or are you disabling scrolling so the text view sizes its height based on its text?

Comment: yes the textview height is fixed

Comment: OK - just a little more clarification on what you're trying to do... Do you want the "placeholder" text to be top-aligned inside the text view? What should happen if the "placeholder" text ends up being, say, 20 lines long? Should it be scrollable? Or, as soon as the user interacts with the text view, does the "placeholder" text become editable? Or does it disappear?

Comment: yes I would prefer to let the maximum number of lines on the placeholder to go to 2
I have ensured that the placeholder cant exceed 80 char. which can be done in 2 lines

Comment: OK - show the code you have so far... how you're adding the label, constraints, etc.